# grep: command not found

Tags: terminal, command-line

This is a very weird behavior. Lately, whenever I am trying to find a process on console with `ps aux | grep foo`, it is returning a `grep: command not found`. Ok, that could be something that I changed and did wrong, but the problem is that, after a few tries, it suddenly knows what `grep` is:

```
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
-bash:  grep: command not found
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
-bash:  grep: command not found
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
-bash:  grep: command not found
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
MM            70953   0,0  0,0  2699108    744   ??  Ss   10:32AM   0:08.77 foo bar
MM             3756   0,0  0,0  2423356    204 s004  R+   10:12AM   0:00.00 grep foo
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

As suggested, this is what I get when a enter `type grep` after both, the one failing and the one working:

```
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
-bash:  grep: command not found
MM:.dev$ type grep
grep is /usr/bin/grep
MM:.dev$ ps aux | grep foo
MM             5694   0,0  0,0  2433796    676 s006  S+   10:47AM   0:00.00 grep foo
MM:.dev$ type grep
grep is /usr/bin/grep
```

Comment: Strange. Do you retype the command every time or just scroll back in the command history?

Comment: I was about to write that. When I scroll back it does not work. If I write it back, it doesn't work either. But if I scroll back and delete the `grep` and the pipe, it eventually works. O_O

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looking at your output, there seems to be an extra space before `grep` in the error message. I assume this is coming from a still pressed <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd> key after typing the pipe symbol (so you basically are typing <kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Space</kbd>). Try `ps aux |grep foo` (without a space between the pipe and the `g`).

Comment: That's it :D Normally, I use emacs, and there when I accidentally type Opt+Space I can see something similar to `_`. So in the terminal, I was just missing that. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh my god.. happened so often to me and that was simply it. how silly!

Comment: this has happened so many times to me, thanks so much for your answer, really appreciate it, i'll be sure to type |grep from now on !! I've been wondering about this one for years!

Answer (score 7):

My answer may sound strange, but I had this effect with an old keyboard as well when I typed too fast. Just try typing it again, move with your cursor before the letter "g" of grep, delete the whitespace that could have been entered with a still pressed <kbd>ALT/Option</kbd> key, hit the space key again and fire up your commandline.

Another workaround is to lower the keyboard repeat rate in System Preferences, if you are not typing with ten fingers. :-)

Comment: That was it! @patrix suggested that too. Stupid of me for not realizing, but sometimes I just want to type too fast. Thanks.